# Calling another constructor AND parent's constructor inside a constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Consider the following class:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

   public MyPanel() {
      super();

      // Do stuff
   }

   public MyPanel(LayoutManager manager) {
      super(manager);

      // Do same stuff as the first constructor, this() can't be used
   }

}
```

The problem arises in the second constructor, when trying to avoid duplicate code. This since I can't call both `super()` and `this()` in the same constructor.

I can extract the common code into a separate method, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Please feel free to update the title if you can describe it in a better way, couldn't find the words. :-)

Comment: Most people agree that a constructor should be kept as simple as possible...so if your "stuff" is more than just some variable assignments, I would suggest to use a method to extract the common code. Otherwise maybe an initializer might do the trick.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig why? I mean besides the basic principal of keeping anything as simple as possible :)

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig Shouldn't *all* code be kept as simple as possible?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Clearly one of those topics where you can keep discussing for days and never reach a real verdict. ;) It's basically what I learned and I've always stuck with it because I really like constructors to be as simple as possible. Make sure the class is brought to the correct state and be done with it. Anyway...having a method to recreate a correct object state can be useful. :)

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig I agree that method to recreate state is useful. I was thinking that if you acquire resources in constructor it necessarily becomes complex, except for moving it to another method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst you just can't invoke more than one constructor, what you can do is something like this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

  public MyPanel() {
     this(null);
  }

  public MyPanel(LayoutManager manager) {
     super(manager);
     // Do all the stuff
  }

}
```

But you might end up with something more messy. As you said, an initialization method can be another way to go:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

  public MyPanel() {
     super();
     this.initialize();
  }

  public MyPanel(LayoutManager manager) {
     super(manager);
     this.initialize();
     // Do the rest of the stuff
  }

  protected void initialize() {
     // Do common initialization
  }

}
```

Comment: is this just a combination of the other two answers?

Comment: Seems so, but there was no answer at the time I started writing this :). If it's useful then excellent, if not well, bad luck.

Answer (score 5):

One pattern often used is

```
class MyPanel extends Panel {
  MyPanel() {
    this(null);
  }

  MyPanel(LayoutManager manager)
    super(manager);
    // common code
  }
}
```

But that only works if `Panel()` and `Panel(null)` are equivalent.

Otherwise, a common methods seems the best approach.

Comment: Or, instead of passing null, you could pass a new FlowLayout() to this(LayoutManager manager) since that's the JPanel default.

Comment: @splungebob I really don't know these classes much but I was trying to give a general solution